# How to use virtualenv in makefile

Tags: python, makefile, virtualenv

I want to perform several operations while working on a specified virtualenv.

For example command

```
make install
```

would be equivalent to

```
source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In make you can run a shell as command. In this shell you can do everything you can do in a shell you started from comandline. Example:

```
install:
    ( \
       source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate; \
       pip install -r requirements.txt; \
    )
```

Attention must be paid to the `;`and the `\`.

Everything between the open and close brace will be done in a single instance of a shell.

Comment: There's no need for the `()` in this case. make already spawns a new shell instance for each line in a rule body. You just need to use the continuation markers to have make read the lines and execute them in a single shell instead of in multiple shells as it would by default.

Comment: @Yukulélé: Please don't change my answer to somewhat which is also posted here as a solution. user2693845 posted exactly what you edited my answer to. The comment from Etan already explains that the braces are not needed...

Comment: I was getting "source: command not found" so I ended up having to use the synonym. Ex changing 3 above: `. path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate; \` I hope this helps anyone else that stumbles here :-)

Answer (score 84):

I like using something that runs only when `requirements.txt` changes:

This assumes that source files are under `project` in your project's root directory and that tests are under `project/test`.  (You should change `project` to match your actually project name.)

```
venv: venv/touchfile

venv/touchfile: requirements.txt
    test -d venv || virtualenv venv
    . venv/bin/activate; pip install -Ur requirements.txt
    touch venv/touchfile

test: venv
    . venv/bin/activate; nosetests project/test

clean:
    rm -rf venv
    find -iname "*.pyc" -delete
```

- Run `make` to install packages in `requirements.txt`.
- Run `make test` to run your tests (you can update this command if your tests are somewhere else).
- run `make clean` to delete all artifacts.

Comment: This looks slick. Can anyone explain it in greater detail?

Comment: What additional information are you looking for? I can add to the answer.

Comment: @oneself what should be run to activate what

Comment: This will delete `venv/bin/activate` if the pip install fails. It's better to use another "tracking file". Just change all occurrences (except sourcing it, of course) to something like `venv/bin/updated_by_make`

Comment: @AntonioBarreto good point, I've updated the answer.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but can someone please explain what is a `touchfile` here? Also how is just typing `make` installs all packages in `requirements.txt`. I have made a similar makefile, but using just `make` outputs `make help` for me. :(

Comment: @zean_7 just typing `make` executes the first target in the makefile, in this case `venv`. Since `venv` depends on `venv/touchfile`, that recipe is run too, provided `requirements.txt` (its dependency) has changed. `venv/touchfile` is just an empty file for tracking modification time of the virtual environment.

Comment: ❯ make                                                                                            ─╯
make: *** No rule to make target `requirements.txt', needed by `venv/touchfile'.  Stop.

Comment: Since the make targets run in another shell, the virtual environment won't be activated for the user's main shell right?

Answer (score 45):

Normally `make` runs every command in a recipe in a different subshell. However, setting `.ONESHELL:` will run all the commands in a recipe in the same subshell, allowing you to activate a virtualenv and then run commands inside it.

Note that `.ONESHELL:` applies to the whole Makefile, not just a single recipe. It may change behaviour of existing commands, details of possible errors in the full documentation. This will not let you activate a virtualenv for use outside the Makefile, since the commands are still run inside a subshell.

Reference documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html

Example:

```
.ONESHELL:

.PHONY: install
install:
    source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: on my opinion it's best solution

Answer (score 21):

I have had luck with this.

```
install:
    source ./path/to/bin/activate; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt; \
```

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Comment: @Adil Add for example this to the first row of the makefile: ``SHELL := /bin/bash``. Adjust to whichever shell you use.

Comment: @Adil, or use POSIX dot command instead of `source`, like `. ./path/to/bin/activate`

Answer (score 19):

This is an alternate way to run things that you want to run in virtualenv.

```
BIN=venv/bin/

install:
    $(BIN)pip install -r requirements.txt

run:
    $(BIN)python main.py
```

PS: This doesn't activate the virtualenv, but gets thing done. Hope you find it  clean and useful.

Comment: Worked on macOS, unlike other recopied

Answer (score 17):

I like to set my Makefile up so that it uses a `.venv` directory if one exists, but defaults to using the PATH.

For local development, I like to use a virtual environment, so I run:

```bash
# Running this:  # Actually runs this:
make venv        # /usr/bin/python3 -m venv .venv
make deps        # .venv/bin/python setup.py develop
make test        # .venv/bin/python -m tox
```

If I'm installing into a container though, or into my machine, I might bypass the virtual environment by skipping `make venv`:

```bash
# Running this:  # Actually runs this:
make deps        # /usr/bin/python3 setup.py develop
make test        # /usr/bin/python3 -m tox
```

### Setup

At the top of your Makefile, define these variables:

```
VENV           = .venv
VENV_PYTHON    = $(VENV_PYTHON)/bin/python
SYSTEM_PYTHON  = $(or $(shell which python3), $(shell which python))
# If virtualenv exists, use it. If not, find python using PATH
PYTHON         = $(or $(wildcard $(VENV_PYTHON)), $(SYSTEM_PYTHON))
```

If `./.venv` exists, you get:

```
VENV          = .venv
VENV_PYTHON   = .venv/bin/python
SYSTEM_PYTHON = /usr/bin/python3
PYTHON        = .venv/bin/python
```

If not, you get:

```py
VENV          = .venv
VENV_PYTHON   = .venv/bin/python
SYSTEM_PYTHON = /usr/bin/python3
PYTHON        = /usr/bin/python3
```

*Note: `/usr/bin/python3` could be something else on your system, depending on your `PATH`.*

Then, where needed, run python stuff like this:

```
$(PYTHON) -m tox
$(PYTHON) -m pip ...
```

You might want to create a target called "`venv`" that creates the `.venv` directory:

```
$(VENV_PYTHON):
    rm -rf $(VENV)
    $(SYSTEM_PYTHON) -m venv $(VENV)

venv: $(VENV_PYTHON)
```

And a `deps` target to install dependencies:

```
deps:
    $(PYTHON) setup.py develop
    # or whatever you need:
    #$(PYTHON) -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Example

Here's my Makefile:

```
# Variables
VENV           = .venv
VENV_PYTHON    = $(VENV)/bin/python
SYSTEM_PYTHON  = $(or $(shell which python3), $(shell which python))
PYTHON         = $(or $(wildcard $(VENV_PYTHON)), $(SYSTEM_PYTHON))

## Dev/build environment

$(VENV_PYTHON):
    rm -rf $(VENV)
    $(SYSTEM_PYTHON) -m venv $(VENV)

venv: $(VENV_PYTHON)

deps:
    $(PYTHON) -m pip install --upgrade pip
    # Dev dependencies
    $(PYTHON) -m pip install tox pytest
    # Dependencies
    $(PYTHON) setup.py develop

.PHONY: venv deps

## Test

test:
    $(PYTHON) -m tox

.PHONY: test

## Build source distribution, install

sdist:
    $(PYTHON) setup.py sdist

install:
    $(SYSTEM_PYTHON) -m pip install .

.PHONY: build install
```

Comment: What is `or` and `wildcard` ? what are you using as a CLI?

Comment: @Kuzeko `$(or val1, val2)` will return the first non-empty value. `$(wildcard path)` returns the path if the file exists. I left the common `SHELL = /bin/...` out of this example because it will work with `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`, which are the common shells to use with makefiles.

Comment: Is the actual default path `./venv` or `./.venv`? Commands and comments refer to both, so I believe there's a typo somewhere...

Comment: The `VENV_PYTHON    = $(VENV_PYTHON)/bin/python` assignment is invalid

Answer (score 7):

Based on the answers above (thanks @Saurabh and @oneself!) I've written a reusable Makefile that takes care of creating virtual environment and keeping it updated: https://github.com/sio/Makefile.venv

It works by referencing correct executables within virtualenv and does not rely on the "activate" shell script. Here is an example:

```
test: venv
    $(VENV)/python -m unittest

include Makefile.venv
```

Differences between Windows and other operating systems are taken into account, Makefile.venv should work fine on any OS that provides Python and make.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but here's my usual setup:

```
# system python interpreter. used only to create virtual environment
PY = python3
VENV = venv
BIN=$(VENV)/bin

# make it work on windows too
ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
    BIN=$(VENV)/Scripts
    PY=python
endif


all: lint test

$(VENV): requirements.txt requirements-dev.txt setup.py
    $(PY) -m venv $(VENV)
    $(BIN)/pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
    $(BIN)/pip install --upgrade -r requirements-dev.txt
    $(BIN)/pip install -e .
    touch $(VENV)

.PHONY: test
test: $(VENV)
    $(BIN)/pytest

.PHONY: lint
lint: $(VENV)
    $(BIN)/flake8

.PHONY: release
release: $(VENV)
    $(BIN)/python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload

clean:
    rm -rf $(VENV)
    find . -type f -name *.pyc -delete
    find . -type d -name __pycache__ -delete
```

I did some more detailed [writeup](https://venthur.de/2021-03-31-python-makefiles.html) on that, but basically the idea is that you use the system's Python to create the virtual environment and for the other targets just prefix your command with the `$(BIN)` variable which points to the `bin` or `Scripts` directory inside your venv. This is equivalent to the `activate` function.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use the environment variable called "VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT". Like this:

```
install:
    ( \
       source $$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT; \
       pip install -r requirements.txt; \
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found prepending to `$PATH` and adding `$VIRTUAL_ENV` was the best route:

- No need to clutter up recipes with `activate` and constrain oneself to `;` chaining

  - Shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801227) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24736236)
- Can simply use `python` as you would normally, and it will fall back onto system Python

  - No need for third party packages
  - Compatible with both Windows (if using `bash`) and POSIX

```
# SYSTEM_PYTHON defaults to Python on the local machine
SYSTEM_PYTHON = $(shell which python)

REPO_ROOT = $(shell pwd)
# Specify with REPO_ROOT so recipes can safely change directories
export VIRTUAL_ENV := ${REPO_ROOT}/venv
# bin = POSIX, Scripts = Windows
export PATH := ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin:${VIRTUAL_ENV}/Scripts:${PATH}
```

And for those interested in example usages:

```
# SEE: http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
SHELL=/bin/bash -euo pipefail
.DEFAULT_GOAL := fresh-install

show-python:    ## Show path to python and version.
    @echo -n "python location: "
    @python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable, end='')"
    @echo -n ", version: "
    @python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version())"

show-venv: show-python
show-venv:  ## Show output of python -m pip list.
    python -m pip list

install: show-python
install:    ## Install all dev dependencies into a local virtual environment.
    python -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt --progress-bar off

fresh-install:  ## Run a fresh install into a local virtual environment.
    -rm -rf venv
    $(SYSTEM_PYTHON) -m venv venv
    @$(MAKE) install
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use this, it's functional for me at moment.

```
report.ipynb : merged.ipynb
    ( bash -c "source ${HOME}/anaconda3/bin/activate py27; which -a python; \
        jupyter nbconvert \
        --to notebook \
        --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python2 \
        --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=3000 \
        --execute merged.ipynb \
        --output=$< $<" )
```