# Activate virtualenv in Makefile

Tags: makefile

How can I activate virtualenv in a Makefile?

**I have tried:**

```
venv:
    @virtualenv venv

active:
    @source venv/bin/activate
```

**And I've also tried:**

```
active:
    @. venv/bin/activate
```

and it doesn't activate virtualenv.

Comment: I think what's he is asking is that if a do `make` my shell will use this environment. You'll see the `(venv)` in from of your hostname.

Answer (score 16):

**Here's how to do it:**

You can execute a shell command in a Makefile using ();

**E.g.**

```
echoTarget: 
    (echo "I'm an echo")
```

Just be sure to put a tab character before each line in the shell command.
i.e. you will need a tab before (echo "I'm an echo")

**Here's what will work for activating virtualenv:**

```
activate:
    ( \
       source path/to/virtualenv/activate; \
       pip install -r requirements.txt; \
    )
```

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`

Comment: try changing "source" to this:    bash -c "source path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate";

Comment: This might install the requirements for the given environment but the user still has to initiate the environment via a shell command. This does not fix the problem. `make` somehow needs to run as the current shell process (if i understand correctly).

Comment: Try using `.  venvpath/bin/activate` in place of `source`

Comment: `make` might be using `sh` instead of `bash`. `source` is a bash-ism while `.` is the standard POSIX way, hence more portable. This is why it might make a difference.

Comment: Just found a SO answer which explains how to use `bash` `Makefile`s
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589276/how-can-i-use-bash-syntax-in-makefile-targets

Comment: @Pobe is right. Even that the requirements are properly installed into venv, it is not activated in the current shell that `make` was run

Comment: @Regis Santos put `SHELL:=/bin/bash` in the `Makefile` to set shell to `bash`.

Answer (score 15):

**UPD Mar 14 '21**

One more variant for `pip install` inside virtualenv:

```
# Makefile

all: install run

install: venv
    : # Activate venv and install smthing inside
    . venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
    : # Other commands here

venv:
    : # Create venv if it doesn't exist
    : # test -d venv || virtualenv -p python3 --no-site-packages venv
    test -d venv || python3 -m venv venv

run:
    : # Run your app here, e.g
    : # determine if we are in venv,
    : # see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1871549
    . venv/bin/activate && pip -V

    : # Or see @wizurd's answer to exec multiple commands
    . venv/bin/activate && (\
      python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'; \
      pip3 -V \
    )

clean:
    rm -rf venv
    find -iname "*.pyc" -delete
```

So you can run `make` with different 'standard' ways:

- `make` - target to default `all`
- `make venv` - to just create virtualenv
- `make install` - to make venv and execute other commands
- `make run` - to execute your app inside venv
- `make clean` - to remove venv and python binaries

Comment: With this setup, how can I activate the `venv` in `run`?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach, I've updated an example to answer your question

Comment: What does the `: #` mean?

Comment: Why the "test -d venv" isn't checking whether things already exist one of the buildin features of a makefile?

Comment: how is this `. venv/bin/activate` working for you ? this is totally wrong, its not activating the venv. even if it try `venv/bin/activate` (which is binary) it says permission denied

Answer (score 2):

I built a simple way to do that by combining an `ACTIVATE_LINUX:=. venv/bin/activate` variable with `.ONESHELL:` at the begging of the Makefile:

```
.ONESHELL:
.PHONY: clean venv tests scripts

ACTIVATE_LINUX:=. venv/bin/activate

setup: venv install scripts
    
venv:
    @echo "Creating python virtual environment in 'venv' folder..."
    @python3 -m venv venv

install:
    @echo "Installing python packages..."
    @$(ACTIVATE_LINUX)
    @pip install -r requirements.txt

clean:
    @echo "Cleaning previous python virtual environment..."
    @rm -rf venv
```

As pointed out in other answers, `Make` recipes run on `sh` instead of `bash`, so using `.` in the `ACTIVATE_LINUX` variable instead of `@` to activate the virtual environment is the correct syntax.

I combined this strategy with `.ONESHELL:`. As shown at [this StackOverflow anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404948/11755155), normally `Make` runs every command in a recipe in a different subshell. However, setting `.ONESHELL:` will run all the commands in a recipe in the same subshell, allowing you to activate a virtual environment and then run commands inside it. That's exactly what's happening in `make install` target and this approach could be applied wherever you need an activated environment to run some python code in your project.

So you can run the following make targets:

- `make` - target to default setup;
- `make venv` - to just create virtual environment;
- `make install` - to activate `venv` and execute the `pip install` command; and
- `make clean` - to remove previous `venv` and python binaries.

Comment: activating the venv is not working as per your `install` phase

Answer (score 1):

> When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe. --- [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution)

Since each line of the recipe executes in a separate sub-shell, we should run the python code in the same line of the recipe.

Simple python script for showing the current source of python environment (filename: `whichpy.py`):

```py
import sys
print(sys.prefix)
```

Running python virtual environment (`Make` recipes run on `sh` instead of `bash`, using `.` to activate the virtual environment is the correct syntax):

```
test:
    . pyth3.6/bin/activate && python3.6 whichpy.py
    . pyth3.6/bin/activate; python3.6 whichpy.py
```

Both the above 2 recipes are acceptable and we are free to use backslash/newline to separate one recipe into multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to activate could be use an environment variable in Makefile. For example:

```
.PHONY: venv install

VENV=.venv
PYTHON=$(VENV)/bin/python3

venv:
    python3 -m venv $(VENV)

install: venv
    $(PYTHON) -m pip install -r requirements-dev.txt

isort:
    $(PYTHON) -m isort --check-only .

black:
    $(PYTHON) -m black --check .

mypy:
    $(PYTHON) -m mypy .

flake8:
    $(PYTHON) -m flake8 .

bandit:
    $(PYTHON) -m bandit -r app

lint: isort black mypy flake8 bandit

test:  ## Run tests
    $(PYTHON) -m pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles can't activate an environment directly. This is what worked for me:

```
activate:
    bash -c "venv/bin/activate"
```

If you get a permission denied error make venv/bin/activate executable:

```
chmod +x venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: `activate` should be sourced, not executed. How does `source venv/bin/activate` work for you, instead of your `bash -c...` line?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it: prepend *each* command in `Makefile` with `. venv/bin/activate &&` which must be run under `venv`.

That is, use:

```
target:
  . venv/bin/activate && command
```

instead of

```
target:
  command
```

Comment: activating the venv is not working as per your `target` phase