# Makefiles does not start conda environment

Tags: python, makefile, conda

I have the makefile

```
.PHONY: start-generate

start-generate:
    source activate myenv
    mkdir "data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`"
    python main/datageneration.py ./"data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`" 3
```

but when I run it I get

```
$ make start-generate
source activate myenv
make: source: Command not found
make: *** [start-generate] Error 127
```

although I am able to run `source activate myenv` outside make.

If I alternatively try

```
start-generate:
    ( \
        source activate myenv; \
        mkdir "data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`"; \
        python main/datageneration.py ./"data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`" 3; \
    )
```

I get the error

```
/bin/sh: 2: source: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main/datageneration.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
make: *** [start-generate] Fehler 1
```

The error with pandas is obviously, because the source-command did not work. And regarding that there is the message `/bin/sh: 2: source: not found`. Maybe the issue is that I need `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`? If so, how do I get it?

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python in virtualenv directly.

```
.PHONY: start-generate

start-generate:
    mkdir "data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`"
    /absPATH/python main/datageneration.py ./"data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`" 3
```

or you can do like below:

[How to use virtualenv in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736146/how-to-use-virtualenv-in-makefile)

```
start-generate:
    ( bash -c "source activate myenv; \
        mkdir "data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`"; \
        python main/datageneration.py ./"data_channels_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`" 3" )
```

Comment: That does not work: Everyone has their conda environment somewhere else. When I give the Makefile to a colleague, it won't work anymore if I do it like you suggest.

Comment: Consider different environment, `source activate myenv` the name of virtualenv may be differnet. You can write the Makefile like a unit-test, `init` to create a virtualenv with the name you like `pip install requirements`, then `start-generate`

Comment: In my company we have conventions how "myenv" is supposed to be called, so that is not an issue. I do not want to have a new environment created every time I run start-generate. I am not sure what you mean exactly. Can you post the Makefile you are thinking of?

Comment: I found a way to do it. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736146/how-to-use-virtualenv-in-makefile>

Comment: We got closer, but it does not work yet. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I did it. I added the required code into your answer. Please except the edit.