# Why can't make command see my Python venv directory?

Tags: python, makefile

I'm writing a `Makefile` for my project (using MacOS). I have the following setup command:

```
init:
    python3 -m venv venv
    source venv/bin/activate
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This should create the virtual environment, activate it, and install required libraries.

However, when I run `make init`, I get:

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
make: source: No such file or directory
make: *** [init] Error 1
```

Running these commands manually works, so the `Makefile` can't see my venv directory for some reason. Any idea why?

I considered that it may be executing the second command before the first completes, but I believe the terminal should prevent that...

Comment: Try use absolute path?

Comment: @hstk As in `source /Users/odai/[project]/venv/bin/activate`? That might work but would prevent anyone else from using my makefile. I suppose I could require their path to be added to an env file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404948/16027068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Enis's linked answer in the comments, this solves my issue:

```
init:
    \
    python3 -m venv venv; \
    source venv/bin/activate; \
    pip install --upgrade pip; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt; \
```

The issue is that `Makefile` runs each line as a new shell, which prevents the virtual environment from being activated for subsequent commands.

My above code combines all the commands into a single line (from Make's perspective). Another option is to add the `.ONESHELL:` flag, although that affects the entire `Makefile`.